# how the comparasion of OS are take place ?

Tags: operating-system

how one can say that one OS is better then another.?

```
i am asking specially about mobile OS.
because people says i-phones are better then android phone or blackberry mobile.
i ask you how phone can be compare with OS...
```

its all about hardware. isn't it. if hardware is good enough then its facility will be always good. right.  because OS just maintain system calls & use resources of system in efficient way.

Comment: isnt this question more apt in a discussion forum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I agree. And this extends to desktop computers, I run Windows 3.11 on my Quad core machine. Its all about hardware.